# Moving Instance attributes from module to module

Tags: python, class, init

I am running into quite a hassle, and I am sure it is an easy fix. Although, I have looked everywhere and I couldn't find what I was looking for.

I have three modules, **module1.py**, **module2.py**, **module3.py**

For example, in **module1.py**, I have an initializing class like so:

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ''
        self.age = 0
```

In **module2.py** I create an instance of something using that class like so:

```
from module1 import MyClass
import module3 # this is where i keep my functions that i 
               # repeatedly use for better code management


me = MyClass()
me.name = "John"
me.age = module3.func_that_does_stuff()

module3.example_func(me.name, me.age)  # this function should manipulate the 
                                       # name and age lets say it turns john into 
                                       # rick, and 25 into 30
```

**Module3.py**

```
func_that_does_stuff():
    return 25

example_func(name, age):
    name = "rick"
    age = 30
    return name, age
```

Like I said above, in **module3** I have functions, but here is where I run into the problem. I can pass those `objects` (`me.name` and `me.age`) to the function in another module, but it doesn't seem to update the `me.name` and `me.age`.

so when I try to print in module 2

```
print(me.name)
print(me.age)
```

I get:

```
self.name = "John"
self.age = 25
```

How can I pass the values of objects to another module, do with them as I see fit, and be able to update what `self.name` and `self.age` of the original instanace of `me`??

Hope this made sense.

Comment: Why can't you pass "me" itself?

Comment: This because parameters in python are passed by _value_, not by _reference_. If you have a function `def foo(x):`, you cannot alter the "thing" that `x` refers to in the calling context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in comments by jonrsharpe, the problem here is the direct assignment in your function, which creates new variable in its own name space. Passing the `me` instance directly, instead of its attributes (which are immutable objects) should solve your problem.

As your intention is to access and change the instance attributes, pass directly the `me` instance to the function.

```
module3.example_func(me)
```

And then modify your function to as below, so instance attributes are directly modified.

```
example_func(me):
    me.name = "rick"
    me.age = 30
```

Note, we skip the `return` as we are modifying the object directly.

Comment: thank you that answers it directly! I will instead use the me instance as an argument.

Comment: The fact that e.g. `me.name` is immutable is, while relevant, not key here - this would still happen if it was e.g. a `list`.

Comment: @user3833838 I understand what you are trying to say, but `example_func` **does not** attempt to modify the arguments, it assigns new values to those names.

Comment: What do you mean *"to the context of the question"*? My point is that, in the code the question is specifically about, **the same thing would happen with mutable attributes**.

Comment: I stand corrected and my answer is also corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what `example_func` does:

```
def example_func(name, age): # take two arguments
    name = "rick" # ignore first argument, assign string literal to name
    age = 30 # ignore second argument, assign integer literal to name
    return name, age # return new values
```

and what `module2` does:

```
module3.example_func(me.name, me.age) # pass two objects (that get ignored)
                                      # and ignore the returned values
```

this **does not** modify either:

1. The (immutable!) objects passed as arguments; or
2. The class instance whose attributes those objects are.

You need to assign those returned values back to the instance:

```
me.name, me.age = module3.example_func(me.name, me.age)
```

Alternatively, make `module3.example_func` take a single `MyClass` instance as an argument, and modify it in-place:

```
def example_func(an_instance):
    an_instance.name = "rick"
    an_instance.age = 30
```

Really, though, given how closely `example_func` seems to be coupled to `MyClass`, you should at least consider putting them in the same file.

Comment: what i provided in this question is really really dumbed down and simple. My actual code.. it quite long, especially the function that manipulates a few attributes. For my sanity i want to keep them separated, but I appreciate the help!

Comment: @pypy two of the three suggestions I've made involve keeping them separate.

Answer (score -1):

In Python, even a string or an integer are objects. However, the behaviour of these objects isn't the same as those that inherit from the class `object` (see [immutable objects ...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Python)).
For example :

```
>>> s = "Hello word"
>>> s.foo = 15
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/local00/home/J91272/Bureau/<ipython console> in <module>()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

However,

```
>>> a = lambda x: 1
>>> a.foo = 36
>>> print a.foo
36
```

The attribute foo contains a pointer to a variable.
When we write `a.foo = 36`, a new variable is created and the pointer of foo designs the new created value in the memory.

Passing the variable a.foo to a function doesn't pass the pointer but the variable.
When you modify this variable using an equality such as `par_a = 25` (for a defined function `func(par_a)`) creates a new variable and modifies the pointer of `par_a`.
But the pointer of a.foo stays the same.

If you want to pass the instance as you described, it's better to pass the whole object, such as:

```
example_func(obj):
    obj.name = "rick"
    obj.age = 30
    return obj.name, obj.age
```

Sometimes we prefer to pass only some specific parameters.
It is even not compulsory for non Pythonic functions called from Python.
In this case, I can suggest a mask function such as:

```
# Initial function that can not be modified
def example_func(name, age):
    name = "rick"
    age = 30
    return name, age

# Mask function that allows passing the object
def mask_function(obj):
    ret = example_func(obj.name, obj.age)
    obj.name, obj.age = ret
    return ret
```

I would be interested if there is a more Pythonic solution!